# Moving files to another folder with commits history?

Tags: git, directory

I have a repo with such files: folder1, folder2, file1, file2. I want to transfer all these files to a new folder in this repo, e.g. to the client folder. How can I do this to keep the commit history for this client folder? Then I want to add a folder, e.g. server, next to the client folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv).

For example if you want to move *file1* from *folder1* to *folder2* you need to navigate to *folder1* and run

```
git mv file1 ../folder2/file1
```

You can do the same with the folder. Lets say that you want to move *folder1* inside *folder2*, you need to navigate to the folder which contains the *folder1* and run

```
git mv folder1 folder2
```

You can use the same command for renaming files by giving as second argument the new name of the file.

```
git mv file1 newFileName1
```

After you are done with moving/renaming files you need to commit only the moving/renaming of the files/folders, because otherwise you will loose the history.

Comment: Technically, `git mv` is *not* required. It's the way to go because it's so much easier to get it right that way, though.